# Optimising object retrieval from a large JSON array using jq

Tags: python, json, performance, jq

I need to retrieve an object at a specific index from a massive JSON array. The array contains 2,000,000 objects and the file size is around 5GB.

I've experimented with various approaches using `jq` in combination with Python, but performance remains an issue.
Here are some of the methods I've tried:

1. Direct indexing:

   ```bash
   jq -c '.[100000]' Movies.json
   ```
2. Slurping and indexing:

   ```bash
   jq --slurp '.[0].[100000]' Movies.json
   ```
3. Using `nth()`:

   ```bash
   jq -c 'nth(100000; .[])' Movies.json
   ```

While these methods seem to work, they are too slow for my requirements. I've also tried using streams, which significantly improves performance:

```bash
jq -cn --stream 'nth(100000; fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs)))' Movies.json
```

However, as the index increases, so does the retrieval time, which I suspect is due to how streaming operates.

I understand that one option is to divide the file into chunks, but I'd rather avoid creating additional files by doing so.

JSON structure example:

```json
[
    {
        "Item": {
            "Name": "Darkest Legend",
            "Year": 1992,
            "Genre": ["War"],
            "Director": "Sherill Eal Eisenberg",
            "Producer": "Arabella Orth",
            "Screenplay": ["Octavia Delmer"],
            "Cast": ["Johanna Azar", "..."],
            "Runtime": 161,
            "Rate": "9.0",
            "Description": "Robin Northrop Cymbre",
            "Reviews": "Gisela Seumas"
        },
        "Similars": [
            {
                "Name": "Smooth of Edge",
                "Year": 1985,
                "Genre": ["Western"],
                "Director": "Vitoria Eustacia",
                "Producer": "Auguste Jamaal Corry",
                "Screenplay": ["Jaquenette Lance Gibe"],
                "Cast": ["Althea Nicole", "..."],
                "Runtime": 96,
                "Rate": "6.5",
                "Description": "Ashlan Grobe",
                "Reviews": "Annnora Vasquez"
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

How could I improve the efficiency of object retrieval from such a large array?

Comment: Unless you can "cheat" and use a fixed offset, which seems unlikely given the data, I doubt you can - you have to parse at least as far as the item you want.

Comment: Is the dataset you're working with available online anywhere? It's tough finding sample datasets that large...

Comment: FWIW, for a real-world use case I'd use an indexed database; some of the examples I've seen for searching/modifying/updating individual huge documents are actually from the XML / XQuery world, but do have JSON support.

Comment: can you pre-format the file so that each of your objects is on their own line, then use sed to grab the nth line and then only use jq on that one single line entry.  If you run jq over the entire file it has to actually _parse_ the entire file which is a huge cost. jumping to a specific line would be very cheap in comparison

Comment: @larsks the dataset can be generated using the open-source generator from [DadroitOrganization](https://github.com/DadroitOrganization/Generator), where I utilized the 'Movies.json' from samples and generated 2,000,000 objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to create an intermediary file or database (e.g. along the lines suggested by @pmf) but want something that's faster than `jq --stream`, then consider the "[JSON Machine](https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine)"-based command-line program named [jm](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jm) (or the similar Python-based program named `jm.py`). Assuming `input.json` contains a JSON array and you just want the 1000th item, you could write:

```
jm --limit 1000 input.json | sed -n '$p'
```

or

```
jm.py --limit 1000 input.json | sed -n '$p'
```

The reason these should generally be (slightly?) faster than using `jq --stream` is that JSON Machine does precisely what is needed here: minimally parse the top-level array with a view to "splatting" it.

---

Here is a performance summary (in increasing order of u+s times) for a file, 1e7.json, consisting
of an array of 1e7 objects:

```
                                       u+s(secs)         mrss
jm.py --limit 100000 | sed -n '$p'     1.16          15163392
jm --limit 100000 | sed -n '$p'        1.9           15532032

gojq -n --stream ...skimpy...          2.54          10375168
jq -n --stream ...skimpy...            3.3            1826816

gojq -n --stream ...                   4.47         189091840
jq -n --stream ...                     5.41           1843200

jsonpointer /99999                    17.8         4636860416
```

where `...` is the jq program:

```
nth(99999; fromstream( inputs|(.[0] |= .[1:]) | select(. != [[]]) ))
```

and the skimpy program is:

```
nth(99999; fromstream(1|tostream(inputs)))
```

---

For reference:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -lp jq length 1e7.json
10000000
user 44.65
sys 9.38
          5196390400  maximum resident set size
```

---

Disclosure: I am the author of the jm and jm.py scripts.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this repeatedly, you could create a prepared file of one item per line at the one-time cost of retrieving the last line, and then use that with external tools to perform the actual retrieval, which they can do faster as they only parse for the occurrences of a row delimiter (newline in this case). This way, the JSON parsing happens once only.

For example, using `sed` as the external tool:

```bash
jq -c '.[]' > lines    # slow, once only

sed '100000q;d' lines  # fast, repeatable
:
```

Or `awk`:

```bash
jq -c '.[]' > lines

awk 'NR==100000 {print; exit}' lines
:
```

After that, you can use `jq` again to operate on the item(s) retrieved.

Comment: I played around with a 3.6G file to do some performance testing. Creating the prepared file took 143.794 seconds (roughly 2.5 minutes), but then the retrieval of the 100000th item took only took 25.3 milliseconds with `sed`, and 38.6 milliseconds with `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a tested solution (due to missing data) but I think the expression

```
nth(100000; fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs)))
```

creates 100000 objects and throws them away (except the last).

This expression should avoid that overhead and might be faster:

```
fromstream(1|truncate_stream( inputs | select(.[0][0] == 100000)))
```

Comment: I played around with a 3.6G file to do some performance testing. The `nth(100000; …)` approach which threw away 99999 items finished in 10.645 seconds, while the `select(.[0][0] == 100000)` approach indeed did reach the targeted index faster (in about 7 seconds, tested by watching a run on just `inputs | select(…)`), but then it still kept combing through the entire input (because more items with the same index could theoretically still appear), thus finally returning after 731.528 seconds! Maybe there is some way to cut the streamed input by manually parsing for the final backtracking item?

Comment: WARNING: `jq -n --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))' <<< [1,2,3]` emits nothing!  See the jq FAQ at https://github.com/jqlang/jq/wiki/FAQ#streaming-json-parser

Comment: @pmf - Wrap the expression using `first(_)`